# Sql query group by categoryId having latest publish date

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

In my table I have to fetch latest article group by there category_id with latest publish date  article. I am try this query

```
SELECT * FROM news GROUP BY category_id
```

It gave me first publish articles. How i got article with latest publish date.

Comment: Can you show the table structure?

Comment: Who upvotes this stuff?

Comment: @Strawberry solution is necessary not up-vote or down-vote

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT n1.* 
FROM news n1
join 
(
  select category_id, max(publish_date) as max_publish_date
  from news 
  GROUP BY category_id
) n2 on n1.category_id = n2.category_id 
    and n1.publish_date = n2.max_publish_date
```

Comment: I see what you're doing but isn't this equivalent (because getting the group is hidden) to select * from news order by publish_date desc?

Comment: No, it's not since that query would not consider the `category_id`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one version of the query you want:

```
select n.*
from news n
where not exists (select 1
                  from news n2
                  where n2.category_id = n.category_id and
                        n2.datetime > n.datetime
                 );
```

This will take advantage of an index on `news(category_id, datetime)`.

Answer (score 0):

This returns the group with the most up-to-date article as the first result:

```
select category_id, max(publish_date) 
from news 
group by category_id 
order by max(publish_date) desc
```